# Picker cannot have border

Tags: react-native

the following code doesn't give me desired result

```
<View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
    <Text>Crash type</Text>
    <Picker
        selectedValue={this.state.crash_type}
        style={{borderBottomWidth:1, borderBottomColor: '#cc0000'}}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
            this.setState({crash_type: itemValue})
    }>
        <Picker.Item label="select..." value="" />
        <Picker.Item label="Mogok" value="mogok" />
        <Picker.Item label="Kecelakaan" value="keelakaan" />
        <Picker.Item label="Lainnya" value="lainnya" />
    </Picker>
</View>
```

basically I want to have a picker with a thin underline. the style is just works fine in another input type.
please advice, any help would be appreciated. thanks a lot.

Comment: It's working fine and also displaying border bottom in my system. you should reload or restart your server.

Comment: i did what you've suggested, but still not working.